# Создание и заполнение таблиц в базе данных на php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть скрипт( на PHP 5.3), который создает таблицы в базе данных и заполняет данными из файла `blog.sql` все работает хорошо, но есть один минус в файле `blog.sql` надо постоянно даные разделять такими символами `###_DATA_###`.

Можно ли переписать скрипт, чтобы в файл `blog.sql` не нужно вносить никаких правок (чтобы не нужно разделять данные) ?

Может у вас есть какие-то лучшие варианты данного скрипта.

```
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $database = 'test';
    $username = 'test';
    $password = 'test';

    $connect_install = @mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password); 
    $con_install = @mysql_select_db($database,$connect_install);



    if($con_install){

       @mysql_set_charset("utf8");
       @mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
       $pbe_arr = explode("###_DATA_###",file_get_contents("blog.sql"));
       foreach($pbe_arr as $key => $val){ mysql_query($val) or die(mysql_error()); }

       mysql_close($connect_install);

   }
```

Файл blog.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_profile` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

###_DATA_###

INSERT INTO `admin_profile` (`id`, `login`, `pass`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');

###_DATA_###

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `data_pub` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

###_DATA_###

INSERT INTO `blog` (`id`, `name`, `text`, `image`, `data_pub`) VALUES
(1, 'Самодисциплина за 10 дней: как перейти от думания к деланию', 'Упражнения, техники и методы, содержащиеся в этой книге, собраны из многих источников. Эта книга содержит простейшие и самые быстрые методы для улучшения самодисциплины.', '141893991520.jpg', '1234567890'),
(2, 'Разрешите поинтересоваться в целях повышения образованности...', 'Хотелось бы отметить многое, но основная мысль - книга призвана сформировать характер', '141893841863.jpg', '1418938425');
```

Comment: разделяйте по точкам с запятой. нет?

Comment: Можно выполнять блоки по точке с запятой, благо они присутствуют. Но разделение файла немного усложняется тем, что надо учитывать точки с запятой внутри кавычек, что бы их не принять за разделители. Вопрос в том, а зачем это делается PHP, проще командой mysql, она сама отлично справится

Comment: @Mike Етот скрипт находится в папке `install`. Разделять точкой с запятой пробовал таблицы действительно создает и заполняет, но выводит ошибку `Query was empty`- Запрос был пустой. Может есть какие-то лучшие скрипты для этого?

Comment: Нафиг тебе ПХП для этого? Стандартный mysql клиент и так сработает.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С вашей задачей справится штатная команда `mysql -u пользователь -pпароль имя-базы < blog.sql`.

Но если вам все таки надо это делать с помощью PHP то [вот такая](https://regex101.com/r/cV7cJ5/4) регурярка нормально выбирает блоки для выполнения по `;`, c учетом возможности наличия точек с запятой внутри кавычек, а так же учитывает все нюансы экранирования кавычек. Но если в файле есть еще комментарии, то с ними надо работать отдельно. Для нормального разбора текста выгружаемого `mysqldump` по хорошему надо делать конечный автомат, что бы правильно учесть не только кавычки, но и комментарии. Без учета комментариев ваш код может выглядеть как то так:

```
$file=file_get_contents("blog.sql");
$offset=0;
while( preg_match('/((?:[^;\']*?(?>\'(?:|.*?(?:[^\\\\]|[^\\\\]?(?:\\\\{2})+))\'))*.*?);/s',
                  $file,$match,0,$offset) )
{
 $sql=$match[1];
 $offset+=strlen($sql)+1;
 $sql=preg_replace("/^[\\\r\\\n]+/","",$sql);
 if(strlen($sql)<=3) continue;
 mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите как сделать сообщение, после успешного создания таблиц и заполнения данными, нужно делать запрос в базу данных или можно здесь в скрипте вывести через `echo "Данные успешно загружено";`

Comment: Ну да, можно после цикла echo сделать. А в цикле я бы тогда какой нибудь счетчик `$cnt++` сделал и писал бы в конце что то типа "выполнено $cnt строк sql".

Comment: Еще раз спасибо.